# Django rename column when multiple tables are joined

Tags: python, django, django-models, jsonresponse

I have this class in models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=20000)
```

The Customer has one to one relationship with User class.
The User class is the default User class in Django:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I want to return result like this:

```html
    "customers": [
        {
            "code": a1,
            "username": "arashb91",            
            "email": "arash@example.com",
            "phone": "111111",
            "address": "somewhere",
            "balance": 20000
        },
```

but when I use this code:

```
result = Customer.objects.all().values("code", 'user__username', 'user__email', "phone", "address", "balance")
```

my result will be like this:

```html
    "customers":
        {
            "code": a1,
            "user__username": "arashb91",
            "user__email": "arash@example.com",
            "phone": "111111",
            "address": "somewhere",
            "balance": 20000
        },
```

I can rename fields by F method:

```
result = Customer.objects.all().values("code", username=F('user__username'),
                                       email=F('user__email'), "phone", "address", "balance")
```

But I get this error on "phone", "address","balance":

```
Positional argument after keyword argument
```

"code" is ok because it is before F methods.
Order in results are important for me.

I can't use this code either (F for other fields):

```
result = Customer.objects.all().values("code", username=F('user__username'),
                                       email=F('user__email'), phone=F("phone"))
```

because I get this error:

```
The annotation 'phone' conflicts with a field on the model.
```

I don't want my result be like this:
othertable__field

for solving my problem I used a python code for renaming dictionary keys, But that is not a good option.
what should I do? 
Is there any simple solution for that?

Comment: Use `annotate` before `values`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used annotate , but not before values

Comment: use extras https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Comment: annotate changed the order:

Comment: lookups = Customer.objects.all().annotate(username=F("user__username")).values("code", 'username',
                                                 "balance"))   : balance came after code in the result, not after username

Comment: This should not affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use extras

```py
address = Customer.objects.extra(select={'code': 'code', 'user__username': 'username', 'user__email': 'email'})
```

Comment: maybe I can use it. but please correct syntax. I did something like your code but I got this error: "no such column: user__username"

Comment: that is up to you  and your name of model fields

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could skip `.all()` if you're using `.values()`
Second, here is solution:

```
result = Customer.objects.values("code", "phone").annotate(
    username=F('user__username'), 
    email=F('user__email')
)
```

Comment: it changes the order in the result: "phone" comes after "code" in the result not after username and email.  what do you suggest for it? because I have this problem in my project not only for Customer model. also for other models that I created. and I want to return result in Json. so Order is important in the answer.